# Defining a c++20 concept for hash functions

Tags: c++, hashtable, c++20, c++-concepts

The CppCoreGuidelines state that concepts should be specified for all template arguments. (see:[T.10: Specify concepts for all template arguments](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-templates)) As practice for defining concepts, I am trying to build a hashtable with concepts defined for the Hash function and Key template arguments.

I want my hashtable to use two template arguments, `HashFunc` and `Key`. `HashFunc` should be a function object and `Key` should be the argument for the function object `HashFunc`.

That is, `HashFunc(Key)` should return a type convertible to `size_t`.

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), there is an example defining the concept `Hashable`. I replicated the example below:

```
template<typename T>
concept Hashable = requires(T a) {
    { std::hash<T>{}(a) } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};
```

This `Hashable` concept makes sense for many uses. In these cases, hash functions on object of type `T` are specializations `std::hash<T>`. However, for my purposes, I don't want to assume that the Hash will be `std::hash<Key>`. I would like the user to be able to provide a different hash function.

Since `HashFunc` and `Key` are so tightly bound, I don't think I can define separate concepts for `HashFunc` and `Key`. **Is that correct?** So I would like to define a concept `HashConcept` that deals with `HashFunc` and `Key` simultaneously.

So I define *one concept* `Hash` that deals with both. I try my best to define the concept so that it matches the named requirement for `Hash` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Hash). The goal then is to satisfy 4 conditions. Below this list, I talk about trying to enforce these conditions.

1. The return type is convertible to `std::size_t`.
2. The hash function displays equality preservation (h(k1) == h(k1) for the duration of the program. see [C++ Extensions for Ranges](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4569.pdf) section 19.1.1)
3. If `u` is an lvalue `Key`, then `h(u)` does not modify `u`.
4. "The probability of `h(a)==h(b)` for `a!=b` should approach `1.0/std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`."

**Does this list appear complete?**

I don't believe concepts can enforce (4), and (4) will just need to be indicated in comments/documentation. I believe that concepts might be able to enforce (2) and (3), but I'm not sure how. [C++ Extensions for Ranges](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4569.pdf) section 19.5 defines the concepts `Callable` and `RegularCallable`, then says "Note: The distinction between Callable and RegularCallable
is purely semantic. — end note", suggesting that (2) cannot be enforced. That leaves (1) and (3).

I define a concept that enforces (1).

```
template<typename HashFunc, typename Key>
concept Hash = requires(HashFunc h, Key k) {
    { std::invoke(h, k) } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};
```

**Is this concept correct? (e.g., should I have used `requires` or returned a `bool`?) Can my concept be extended to address other requirements for hash functions, such as (2)-(4)?**

Below is some example code that uses the concept. The result is to print `3` to the `std::cout`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template<typename HashFunc, typename Key>
concept HashConcept = requires(HashFunc h, Key k) {
    { std::invoke(h, k) } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};


class HashFunc {
public:
    std::size_t operator()(int i) {
        return static_cast<size_t>(i);
    }
};

template<typename Hash, typename Key>
    requires HashConcept<Hash, Key>
size_t HashConceptUser(Hash h, Key k) {
    return h(k);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << HashConceptUser< HashFunc, int >(HashFunc{}, 3); 

}
```

Comment: `HashFunc`'s call operator is private.

Comment: @Barry Thanks, I have edited the question to remove the error to prevent confusion.

Comment: Not reproductible since your call operator is public: https://godbolt.org/z/f777cP

Comment: The (3) could be enforceable by taking `const Key& k` instead of `Key k`. If someone breaks this precondition (by legal or illegal `const_cast`) then, well, I guess it is *almost* 
 (or actual) UB on their part.

Comment: There is no reason to explicitly provide template parameters. It's a function template, let deduction do its thing.

Comment: explicitly providing template parameters 1. makes it easier to find errors in code and 2. documents for others what my code should be doing.

Comment: @Fureeish take ```const Key& k``` where? In the ```HashConceptUser``` by ```size_t HashConceptUser(Hash h, const Key& k)```?

Comment: @mana I disagree strongly with both statements. It certainly makes it easier to _introduce_ errors by getting the types wrong.

Comment: if I get the types wrong, then that means I probably didn't understand what my code is doing. If I get a compiler error, then I am happy.

Comment: @mana `requires(HashFunc h, Key k)` -> `requires(HashFunc h, const Key& k)`. This will either ensure that `HashFunc` takes its parameter by `const&` or by value - either way, it cannot (unless `const_cast`, but if the programmer **really wants** to break something, they **will**) change the passed argument.

Comment: @Fureeish I'm confused by how cv-qualification works with ```requires```, but your suggestion appears to work. I made the change you suggested and changed the ```operator()``` function to ```std::size_t operator()(int& i) { i += 1; return static_cast<size_t>(i); }```. The compiler caught the error as you said.

Comment: @mana `requires` is "*given*" the arguments and tests some conditions given those exact arguments. When given just the `const&`, it will, well, *require* those tests to pass when given `const&`.

Comment: *""The probability of `h(a)==h(b)` for `a!=b` should approach `1.0 / std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`"* - this may be impractical to enforce with concepts, but anyway - your identity hash has probability 0, and the desirable quality is really that the probability *after `% bucket_count()`* - for any possible `bucket_count()` - doesn't significantly exceed `1.0/table_size`.  That can vary with implementation (e.g. GCC standard hash containers use prime bucket counts, Visual C++ uses powers of 2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this list appear complete?

The list is missing arguably the single most important criteria for a hash function: that if `a == b` then `h(a) == h(b)`.

The 4th criterion on the list is something you want for *good* hash functions, and is itself somewhat incomplete - you don't just want the likelihood of collision to be small, you also want random dispersion. The hash function `h(i) = i` satisfies the 4th criterion, but not a good hash function. On the flip side, `h(i) = 0` is a terrible hash function but should be considered valid.

---

That said, C++ language concepts cannot *enforce* any of these things - you cannot enforce that the hash function is equality-preserving, you cannot enforce that it doesn't modify its inputs, and you cannot enforce anything about the distribution of its results. Those are what we would call *semantic* constraints rather than syntactic ones (the C++ standard  speaks of *satsifying* a concept if the syntactic constraints are met and *modeling* a concept if the syntactic and semantic ones are met). The semantic constraints are documented requirements (in comments, or just documentation) rather than coded ones.

The best you can do the syntax is just verify that the hash function is invocable and gives you an integer:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename T>
concept HashFor = std::regular_invocable<F, T>
               && std::convertible_to<std::invoke_result_t<F, T>, size_t>;
```

I am using `regular_invocable` here because [that concept](https://eel.is/c++draft/concept.regularinvocable) adds semantic constraints that you want: that the function call is equality-preserving and does not modify the function object or its arguments. You could also write it this way:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename T>
concept HashFor = std::regular_invocable<F, T>
    && requires(F f, T t) {
        { std::invoke(f, t) } -> std::convertible_to<size_t>;
    };
```

But I would keep the `regular_invocable` part.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that C++20 Concepts can't deal with semantic constraints, only syntactic constraints. So your criteria (2) and (4) are right out. (And Barry is right that your (2) was way too weak; the correct stronger criterion, `h(i)==h(j) if i==j`, is also right out.) So really your question is, "What is *syntactically* required of a hasher in C++?"

As Eric Niebler once said, you don't find concepts by looking at types (the implementors of concepts), you find concepts by looking at algorithms (the users of concepts). So this question boils down to, "What does `unordered_set` syntactically require of its hasher?"

- `H` must be copyable, assignable, etc., or else your `unordered_set<K, H>` won't be copyable, assignable, etc. (Arguably a move-only hasher could produce a move-only `unordered_set`, but in practice that's not how it works. E.g. [`s.hash_function()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/hash_function) requires copyability.)
- `H` must be default-constructible, or else your `unordered_set` won't be default-constructible.
- `H` must be both callable and const-callable, with both const and non-const lvalues and rvalues of type `K`. (If `H` isn't const-callable, you won't be able to look anything up in a const `unordered_set`.)

(As of 2023, libc++ encodes some of these requirements in [`__check_hash_requirements`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/6256ccfd4f0/libcxx/include/__functional/hash.h#L657-L668). You might look there for inspiration.)

So you might make a concept something like

```
template<class F, class... Args>
concept SizeTPredicate =
  std::regular_invocable<F, Args...> &&
  std::convertible_to<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>, size_t>;

template<class H, class K>
concept HashFor =
  std::semiregular<H> &&
  SizeTPredicate<H&, K&> &&
  SizeTPredicate<H&, const K&> &&
  SizeTPredicate<const H&, K&> &&
  SizeTPredicate<const H&, const K&>;
```

However, in practical terms, the four calls to `SizeTPredicate` are both overkill *and* arguably insufficient — arguably we might also want to encode that `H&` is callable with `K&&`, for example, or that `H&&` is callable with `const K&` (e.g. `s.hash_function()(*s.begin())` should be well-formed). I say "arguably" because here we're drifting away from what the algorithm *actually requires* and into "stuff we just thought up." That is usually a very bad idea when it comes to concept design.

So maybe we should mentally classify "`H&` must be callable" and "`H` must be callable with `K&` as well as `const K&`" as basically semantic constraints — we'll pick the one syntactic constraint that best expresses our intent and catches the most user error, and leave the corner cases up to the user's judgment. The result:

```
template<class H, class K>
concept HashFor =
  std::semiregular<H> &&
  std::regular_invocable<const H&, const K&> &&
  std::convertible_to<std::invoke_result_t<const H&, const K&>, size_t>;
```

---

Finally, you might wonder whether we can just omit `std::regular_invocable<X,Y>` from the concept definition — isn't that mechanically implied by our use of `std::invoke_result_t<X,Y>`? (That is, if `X` doesn't satisfy `invocable<Y>`, then `invoke_result_t<X,Y>` will SFINAE away, correctly making our whole concept unsatisfied.) There are two reasons, neither of which is a slam dunk:

- Putting `invocable` right in the constraint, at the top level, allows *subsumption* to work. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6Tfc57jKM):

  ```
    template<class T> requires HashFor<T, int>
    int f(T) { return 1; }  // "more constrained"

    template<class T> requires std::invocable<const T&, const int&>
    int f(T) { return 2; }  // "less constrained"
  ```
- Using `std::regular_invocable` instead of `std::invocable` (or nothing) communicates to the human reader that we intend this thing to be [*regularly invocable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable), i.e., it shouldn't modify its arguments or be nondeterministic; it should be a pure function of its inputs.

Of course the former code is highly unrealistic, and we *could* do the latter with a `// code comment` instead.

---

I feel like there's one more missing semantic criterion, to do with heterogeneous/transparent hashers. Right now we have

```
static_assert(HashFor<std::hash<std::string_view>, std::string>>);
```

which is fine and good — the STL even [goes out of its way to guarantee](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string.hash#1) that `std::hash<std::string_view>()(s) == std::hash<std::string>()(s)` for all strings `s`. But we also have

```
static_assert(HashFor<std::hash<std::string_view>, const char*>>);
```

even though `std::hash<std::string_view>()(p) != std::hash<const char*>()(p)` for most pointers `p`, and even though `std::hash<std::string_view>()(nullptr)` has undefined behavior. This *feels* like a problem. But, at the same time, we obviously do want to permit people to create `unordered_set<const char*, hash<string_view>, equal_to<string_view>>` — there's nothing catastrophic about that! So I think this is simply a semantic constraint on `H`: ordinary usage of `H` shouldn't result in UB or otherwise do anything "unexpected" by the user. All we can do with our concept is encode *what usages* we expect; we can't encode exactly what we mean by "unexpected behavior," except in ordinary language via comments and documentation. This is exactly analogous to how

```
static_assert(std::totally_ordered<float>);
```

is true, even though `float(std::nan(""))` isn't actually part of that "total" order. Likewise, we'll let

```
static_assert(HashFor<std::hash<std::string_view>, const char*>>);
```

be true, even though `std::hash<std::string_view>` can't actually hash `(const char*)nullptr`. As long as the user plays along and excludes the special value from their domain, we'll be okay.